# Solving difficult exponent equation $x^a-x^b=c$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

I have the following equation (derived from a bunch of steps prior but this is the last step that matters)
$$
x^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{p^2}}-x^{\frac{p+1}{p}} = \log(p)
$$
and need to find $x$ given a value of $p$.

It is also sufficient to simplify the notation down to the equivalent form
$$
x^a-x^b = c
$$

This can obviously be calculated numerically, but I would like to have an analytic solution, or at least $\color{blue}{\textrm{a lower bound approximation}}$ which is analytic.

I attempted to get it into a form that could be solved but got stuck (even when using Lambert W functions and such).

If there exists no analytical solution that is also acceptable (albiet sad) to learn

---

**Edit:**

This problem actually arises because I wanted to find the maximum value $x$ that satisfies the inequality
$$
x^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{p^2}}-x^{\frac{p+1}{p}} < \log(p)
$$
where $p\in\mathbb{Z}\geq 3$, which is why a lower bound of the value of $x$ that satisfies the inequality would be acceptable as well (and prefered over an upper bound!)

Comment: For any $\epsilon$, we have $p^{2-\epsilon}<x<p^2$ when $p$ is sufficiently large......

Comment: Btw, you can slightly simplify it to $y^d-y = c$.
Unfortunately, this kind of equation is known to
have no analytic solution 
(even in terms of the Lambert W) in general,
except some special simpler cases.

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting problem ! I had a lot of fun and we could do much better.

Comment: Would you mind to reset the question as it was at the beginning (roll back the edit). I have received comments telling that my answer was good for the first version but not for the presnt one (peer review). The, post another question for the inequality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici a new question was posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4011862/426335

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4456799/how-to-solve-related: not-numerically-the-inequality-xa-xb-c0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial problem is very interesting for numerical analysis.

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=x^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{p^2}}-x^{\frac{p+1}{p}} - \log(p)$$

As @Yuval commented, the solution has to be something like $x=kp^2$ and a quick look at a few numerical results suggest $k\sim \frac 12$.

Making one single iteration of Newton method gives, as an *estimate*,
$$\color{blue}{x_1=\frac 12 p^2+\frac{2^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{p^2}} p^{2-\frac{2}{p}} \log
   (p)+\left(2^{\frac{1}{p^2}}-p^{\frac{2}{p^2}}\right) p^4}{2
   \left(p^{\frac{2}{p^2}} \left(p^2+p+1\right)-2^{\frac{1}{p^2}} p (p+1)\right)}}\tag 1$$

Checking for a few values of $p$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & x_1 & x \\
 5  & 10.4182 &  10.3150 \\
 10 & 41.9375 &  41.7121 \\
 15 & 97.4125 &  97.1441 \\
 20 & 177.728 &  177.450 \\
 25 & 283.307 &  283.035 \\
 30 & 414.389 &  414.132 \\
 35 & 571.127 &  570.890 \\
 40 & 753.622 &  753.406 \\
 45 & 961.947 &  961.754 \\
 50 & 1196.15 &  1195.98 \\
 55 & 1456.29 &  1456.14 \\
 60 & 1742.37 &  1742.24 \\
 65 & 2054.43 &  2054.33 \\
 70 & 2392.49 &  2392.40 \\
 75 & 2756.57 &  2756.49 \\
 80 & 3146.66 &  3146.61 \\
 85 & 3562.80 &  3562.76 \\
 90 & 4004.98 &  4004.95 \\
 95 & 4473.20 &  4473.18 \\
 100 & 4967.49 &  4967.48
\end{array}
\right)$$ which does not look too bad.

We could do better using one iteration of Halley or Householder mathod. The formulae will not be printed here (too long and very massy). To give an idea, for $p=5$, the first iteration of Halley method would give $10.3241$ reducing the $1.000$% relative error to $0.088$% (a factor of $\sim 11.5$). The first iteration of Householder method would give $10.3159$.

**Edit**

If instead of $f(x)$, we consider the function
$$g(x)=\log\Bigg[x^{\frac{p^2+p+1}{p^2}}\Bigg]-\log\Bigg[x^{\frac{p+1}{p}} + \log(p)\Bigg]$$ Let $x=kp^2$ and expand as series for infinitely large $p$, we have
$$g(x)=\frac{\frac{(2 k-1) \log (p)}{k}+\log (k)}{p^2}+\frac{\log (p) \log \left(k
   p^2\right)}{k p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ Cancelling the first term gives
$$k=\frac{\log (p)}{W\left(p^2 \log (p)\right)}\implies \color{blue}{x_0=\frac{p^2\log (p)}{W\left(p^2 \log (p)\right)}}$$ which shows an horizontal asymptote $k_\infty=\frac 12$.

Now, one iteration of Newton method gives $x_1$ which is as good as the one given by $(1)$
$$\color{blue}{x_1=x_0+\frac{p^2 x_0^{-1/p}}{\left(p^2+p+1\right) x_0^{\frac{1}{p^2}}-p (p+1)} \left(\log (p)-x_0^{\frac{1}{p}+1} \left(x_0^{\frac{1}{p^2}}-1\right)\right)}$$

Using it for $p=123.456$, $x_0=8150.37$, $x_1=7636.04$. Now, Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 2 & 7636.0400 \\
 3 & 7634.2367 \\
 4 & 7634.2371
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Wow this is incredible! I think I will wait two days so I can award a bounty to this comment cause its really good. I made a little edit to the problem if you're interested in the inequality version but what you did is more than sufficient!

Comment: @wjmccann. I shall think about the inequality. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lambert-Tsallis function https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046

and $x=\bigg[ - \frac{W_{\frac{r-1}{r}}\big(-r\cdot c^r\big)}{r} \bigg]^{\frac{1}{ar}}$ with $r=\frac{b-a}{a}$
For comparison, there are some values
\begin{bmatrix}
p & r & W & x\\ 
5 & -0.032258064516129 & 0.029383233668222 - 0.000000000000002i & 10.314969147539184 + 0.000000000016275i\\ 
20 &  -0.002375296912114 & 0.002344742828298 + 0.000000000000015i & 1.774496678722473e+02 - 4.482633791812651e-07i\\ 
35 & -7.930214115781222e-04 & 7.889230895529774e-04 - 3.347191976910963e-15i & 5.708895492062650e+02 + 2.967113342902804e-06i \\ 
50 &  -3.920031360250450e-04 & 3.908935021312620e-04 + 1.960839917706131e-14i & 1.195984539674884e+03 - 1.499854956380599e-04i  \\
123.456 & -6.507942319878391e-05 & 6.504125962624690e-05 - 5.446267631807573e-15i & 7.634273815149508e+03 + 9.743212424425975e-03i
\end{bmatrix}

Just to remember, $W_q(z)$ must satisfies the equation
$W_q(z)\cdot \left( 1 + (1-q)\cdot W_q(z)\right)^{\frac{1}{1-q}} = z$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^a-x^b=c$$

Because $a,b$ are rational and $c$ is real, this equation is related to an algebraic equation over the reals and we can use the known solution formulas and methods for algebraic equations.

Also, the equation is in a form similar to a trinomial equation.

$c\to q$:
$$x^a-x^b=q$$
$x\to (qt)^\frac{1}{a}$:
$$qt-q^\frac{b}{a}t^\frac{b}{a}=q$$
$b/a\to\alpha$:
$$qt-q^\alpha t^\alpha=q$$
$$t-q^{\alpha-1}t^\alpha=1$$
$q^{\alpha-1}\to y$:
$$t-yt^\alpha=1$$
$$t-yt^\alpha-1=0$$

Now the equation is in the form of equation 8.1 of [Belkic 2019]. Solutions in terms of Bell polynomials, Pochhammer symbols or confluent [Fox-Wright Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function) $\ _1\Psi_1$ can be obtained therefore.
$\ $

[Szabó, P. G.: On the roots of the trinomial equation. Centr. Eur. J. Operat. Res. 18 (2010) (1) 97-104](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225959964_On_the_roots_of_the_trinomial_equation)

[Belkić, D.: All the trinomial roots, their powers and logarithms from the Lambert series, Bell polynomials and Fox–Wright function: illustration for genome multiplicity in survival of irradiated cells. J. Math. Chem. 57 (2019) 59-106](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10910-018-0985-3)