# How to solve (not numerically) the inequality $x^a-x^b -c>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $x>0$ and $a, b, c\in\mathbb{R}^*_+$ with $b>a$. I am wondering if there is a way (not numerical) to solve the inequality
$$x^a-x^b -c>0.$$

Could someone please help or give some hints?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is $a>b$ or $a\gg b$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici actually it is $b>a$.

Comment: Add it in the question, please

Comment: Let $b>a>0$, $c>0$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive roots of $x^a-x^b-c=0$ such that $0 < x_1 < x_2$, then solution of inequality is $x_1 < x < x_2$. Let mark $x_1 = \eta(a,b,c)$ and $x_2=\zeta(a,b,c)$, then $\eta(a,b,c)< x < \zeta(a,b,c)$. It is analytical solution, however it uses some special functions $\eta$ and $\zeta$.

Comment: One can make number of parameters less: $\eta(a,b,c)=\eta(1,\frac{b}{a},c)^{\frac1a}=\eta_1(\frac{b}{a},c)^{\frac1a}$.

Comment: If $a,b$ are rational numbers, we get an algebraic inequality and can apply the solution theory for algebraic equations.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010624/solving-difficult-exponent-equation-xa-xb-c/4693204#4693204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $b >a>0$, let $x^a=y$, $k=\frac  b a>1$ and the problem becomes
$$f(y)=y-y^k-c >0$$ The first derivative cancels at
$$y_*=k^{-\frac{1}{k-1}} $$ At this point $$ f(y_*)=-c+(k-1)\, k^{-\frac{k}{k-1}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad f''(y_*)=-(k-1)\, k^{\frac{1}{k-1}}~~< ~0$$ So, $y_*$ corresponds to a maximum.

We also have $f(0)=f(1)=-c$. The only way to have roots is that
$$f(y_*)>0 \implies c < (k-1)\, k^{-\frac{k}{k-1}}$$

If this is the case, we can even approximate the solutions as
$$y_{\pm}=y_*\pm \sqrt{-2 \frac{f(y_*)}{f''(y_*)}}$$

Trying with $k=\pi$ and $c=\frac 14$ this would give
$$y_{\pm}=\pi ^{-\frac{1}{\pi -1}}\pm \sqrt{\frac{\pi ^{\frac{1}{1-\pi }} \left(4 (\pi -1) \pi ^{-\frac{\pi }{\pi -1}}-1\right)}{2
   (\pi -1)} } $$ that is to say $y_-=0.299990$ and $y_+=0.871908$ while the solutions are $0.265514$ and $0.849873$.

**Edit**

We could even do better building the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant of $y-y^k$ around $\alpha=y_*$. It would lead to
$$c=\frac{(\alpha -\alpha ^k)-a_1(y-\alpha) -a_2(y-\alpha)^2} {1-b_1(y-\alpha) +b_2(y-\alpha)^2}$$
$$a_1=\frac{(k-3) (k+1) (k+2)\alpha ^{k+1}+k (k+1) (k+2) \alpha ^{2 k}+\alpha ^2 (k-7)
   (k-2)}{2 \alpha  \left(k (k+1) \alpha ^k+2 \alpha  (k-2)\right)}$$
$$a_2=\frac{k (k+1)^2 (k+2) \alpha ^{2 k}-(k-13) (k-2) k (k+1) \alpha ^{k+1}+6 \alpha ^2
   (k-3) (k-2)}{12 \alpha ^2 \left(k (k+1) \alpha ^k+2 \alpha  (k-2)\right)}$$
$$b_1=\frac{(k-2) \left(k (k+1) \alpha ^k+\alpha  (k-3)\right)}{2 \alpha  \left(k (k+1)   \alpha ^k+2 \alpha  (k-2)\right)}$$
$$b_2=\frac{(k-2) (k-1) k (k+1) \alpha ^{k-2}}{12 \left(k (k+1) \alpha ^k+2 \alpha    (k-2)\right)}$$ and we are just left with a quadratic equation in $(y-\alpha)$.

Applied to the worked example, $y_-=0.266710$ and $y_+=0.850368$ which are quite good.

Comment: Why we took $b>a$ ?

Comment: @user. Because it is written in the second comment (answer to my question).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you for the answer. But why the solutions $y_{\pm}$ can be approximated in that way? (I mean using first and second derivative)

Comment: @C.Bishop. Have a look at my edit. This is just Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Over the last 2 years, I have  been working on a new function that is a modification of Lambert, called Lambert-Tsallis $W_q(z)$, originally published at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physa.2019.03.046. $W_q(x)$ is a multivalued function (depending on $q$ value) and it is the solution of the polynomial equation
$$ y \cdot \bigg( 1 + (1-q)\cdot y \bigg)^\frac{1}{1-q} = x$$

After a few manipulations, one can find that

$$x^{ar}\le - \frac{1}{r} \cdot W_{\frac{r-1}{r}} \bigg( -r\cdot c^r \bigg) 
  \  \  \ Eq(1)$$

with $r=\frac{b}{a} -1$. At the original problem $b>a$ so that $r>0$. It is important to emphasize that to arrive at Eq(1) manipulations of the original problem are done, i.e., the original problem implies on Eq(1) but the contrary is not always true. In other words, one has to check the validty of the results found. We will notice that at table below.

For $r>0$ except $r \ne -1$,  $W_q(x)$ function will have at least 2 real solutions. Indeed, it has a branch point, similar to that of Lambert function.
[[image: Real roots of <span class=]$W_q(x)$ function when $r>0$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfdeR.jpg)

The condition posted by @Claude Leibovici corresponds exactly to $z_b < z < 0$, which is in perfect agreement with our analytical solution. However, the main question of the original post (Is there any condition among $a,b,c $ and $x$ ?)  can be written

$$x^{ar} < 1. $$

This is true only for $x \in R$. It can have $x$ satisfying $x^a - x^b =c$ but this previous inequality must not be applied.

Following, lets consider some examples

\begin{matrix}
a & b & c & r & z & W_q(z) & x & x^a - x^b =c\\
+1.0000 & +3.1416 & +0.2500 & +2.1416 & -0.1100 & (-2.61987 , +0.09259i) & (+1.09887 , -0.01813i) & FALSE \\ 
+1.0000 & +3.1416 & +0.2500 & +2.1416 & -0.1100 & (-2.61987 , -0.09259i) & (+1.09887 , +0.01813i) & FALSE \\ 
+1.0000 & +3.1416 & +0.2500 & +2.1416 & -0.1100 & (-1.51162 , -0.00000i) & (+0.84987 , +0.00000i) & TRUE \\ 
+1.0000 & +3.1416 & +0.2500 & +2.1416 & -0.1100 & (-0.12513 , -0.00000i) & (+0.26551 , +0.00000i) & TRUE \\
+2.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.2500 & +4.0000 & -0.0156 & (-4.94821 , +0.00000i) & (+1.02695 , -0.00000i) & FALSE \\ 
+2.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.2500 & +4.0000 & -0.0156 & (-4.05898 , -0.98745i) & (+1.00499 , +0.02999i) & FALSE \\ 
+2.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.2500 & +4.0000 & -0.0156 & (-4.05898 , +0.98745i) & (+1.00499 , -0.02999i) & FALSE \\ 
+2.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.2500 & +4.0000 & -0.0156 & (-2.91795 , -0.00000i) & (+0.96134 , +0.00000i) & TRUE \\ 
+2.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.2500 & +4.0000 & -0.0156 & (-0.01588 , -0.00000i) & (+0.50100 , +0.00000i) & TRUE \\
+2.0000 & +3.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.5000 & -1.5811 & (-0.71687 , +0.90820i) & (+1.43373 , -1.81639i)  & TRUE \\ 
+2.0000 & +3.0000 & +10.0000 & +0.5000 & -1.5811 & (-0.71687 , -0.90820i) & (+1.43373 , +1.81639i)  & TRUE \\  
\end{matrix}

Answer (score 0):

The inequality $$x^a-x^b>c$$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb R_+$ can be solved in exact form, iff the equation $x^a-x^b=c$ has an exact form roots (solutions).

But, this is not always possible. For instance, putting $a=\pi,b=e, c=1$, then we need the root of the equation

$$x^{\pi}-x^e-1=0$$

But, we can not solve this equation using algebraic or special functions.
This is not even a polynomial. However, the inequality  $x^{\pi}-x^e>1$ has a solution in real numbers: $x>1.67788$.

I think the classification of this equation is [Transcendental equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation#:%7E:text=In%20applied%20mathematics%2C%20a%20transcendental,sides%20describes%20a%20transcendental%20function.). If I'm wrong mathematicians can correct me.

But, if $a,b\in\mathbb Z_{≥5}$, then we can always solve the inequality using the [Hypergeometric functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Gaussian%20or,ordinary%20differential%20equation%20(ODE).).

For instance putting $a=5,b=1,c=1$ we need to solve $x^5-x-1=0$, before solving the inequality $x^5-x>1$. But, according to [Galois theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory), we cannot solve this equation using algebraic operations.

Finally note that, we can solve this inequality in [closed form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), when $a,b\in\mathbb Z_{≤4}^{+}.$

Then, knowing the roots of the polynomial $x^a-x^b-c=0$, we can always solve the inequality $x^a-x^b>c$ using algebraic radicals.